# Changing Console Background Color in C# on Mac

Tags: c#, console, background-color

I have written the below code but it's not changing the color of the whole console ...its only having a white background for the text that is written ... what am i doing wrong ?

I am working on visual studio for Mac

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    Console.Clear();

    string userName = "Emile";
    Console.WriteLine(" Hello " + userName + "... what is your family name  ?");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(" So your name is " + userName + " and your family name is {0}, right ? ", userInput);

    Console.Read();
```

Comment: I think you might find that that's just the way it is! The fore and back colors are intended for formatting/highlighting the text you output. If you want a full on beautiful UI, don't write a console app

Comment: Please follow this jerriepelser.com/blog/using-ansi-color-codes-in-net-console-apps/

Comment: But the background is not fully coloring ...the only thing that is coloring is the text that is being written ....